# Cannot run Samsung Tizen NaCl application on tv emulator or real tv

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-native-app, tizen-sdb, tizen-sdk

I am developing a NaCl (Native Client) application for Samsung Tizen TV.

I currently cannot upload and run any application on neither an emulator nor a real Samsung Tizen TV.

Even if I try the sample HelloWorld NaCl application that comes with TizenStudio I still cannot run it on neither the emulator nor the real Samsung Tizen TV.

Here is what I get in the console log. It is the same error regardless whether I use the Emulator or TV.

`IsRootCmd
    Uploading widget...Success!
    install 2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld
    package_path /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/tmp/helloworld.wgt
    was_install_app return WAS_TRUE
    app_id[2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld] install start
    app_id[2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld] installing[8]
    app_id[2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld] installing[11]
    app_id[2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld] installing[14]
    app_id[2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld] installing[17]
    app_id[2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld] installing[20]
    app_id[2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld] installing[22]
    app_id[2UUkJWiVk2.helloworld] install failed[118]
    spend time for wascmd is [527]ms
    cmd_ret:0`

[image: CannotRunOnEmulator]

It seems I am able to upload the application on the Emulator (or real tv) but when it tries to run the application it gets an error.

TizenStudio does not report any more errors. It just says 'Launching helloworld' has encountered a problem. Error during launch. Widget installation failed !

I am using TizenStudio ver 2.0

Here is how I am creating my sample NaCl application

> File -> New -> Other... -> Tizen -> Samsung TV -> Tizen NaCl App (C/C++)

Then I type in a name for the project and click "next". On the following page I select "Example projects", I choose the "hello_world_cpp" sample and click "Finish" to create the project.

I was able to get the NaCl helloworld sample to install and work on the emulator and real TV before. But a week later I cannot install anything on neither my emulator nor my TV. I get the error described above.

I don't know what is causing the problem.

I also deleted and recreated new certificates as instructed on this page:

http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/setting-up-sdk/creating-certificates

But that did not help. To note the last step on that page "Permit to install applications" cannot be performed. There is no device filesystem for me to right-click on.

To note also, I can run the application in a chrome browser. I can do "Run as" -> "Webpage in chrome" and that works.

But when I run on a TV emulator or real TV with "Run as" -> "Widget on a Tizen device", that does not work and I get the error described above.

I would appreciate if anyone has any pointers about how I can debug this problem or what I can try.

Answer (score 4):

I was finally able to get my helloworld NaCl application to be deployed on the Tv or Tv Emulator.

I had to create a Tizen certificate (not a samsung certificate).

The instructions found on this page are wrong as they instruct you to create a samsung certificate:

http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/setting-up-sdk/creating-certificates